# Convert google suggestion result and output to txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the following code to scrape google suggestions:

```
with open(inputfile, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as inputf:
    for line in inputf:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        URL="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=" + line
        headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
        response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
        result = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        print(result)
        with open(outputfile, 'a') as file:
            for num in range(len(result)):
                file.write(result[num] + '\n')
                print('wrote: %s ' %(result[num]))
```

input file:

```
online games
ofline games
free online games
mods
game
gaming
```

json output:

```
['game', ['game mania', 'game of thrones', 'games', 'game of thrones season 8',
          'game of thrones season 7', 'game night', 'gamemeneer', 'gamegear',
          'game pc', 'gamescom']]
```

I want is to output every result to a new line in a text file.
example:

```
game mania\n
game of thrones\n
games\n
ect
```

but I'm getting  the following error:

```
    File "modules/keyword-suggestion-scraper.py", line 50, in <module>
    file.write(result[num] + '\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  There are Python tutorials on line for list access and basic output techniques.  What have you tried, and where is the example showing the point in question?

Comment: im  stuck at how to  extract every result of the json

Comment: Ah -- you might want to update your question.  There's nothing in it that indicates you have a problem converting between list format and JSON.  All you showed was a simple `list`.  Have you searched for tutorials on JSON handling?  Python has a couple of nice packages for reading & writing JSON format.

Comment: updated original comment

Comment: Much better; thanks.  I understand now; and I think the others have your problem covered.  IN the future, please include the *entire* error message, including the trace-back.

Comment: ok will try to add it next time if i think about it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get your output to a list, then itterate through that list as you add your value to the text file like this:

```
mylist = ['one','two','three']
with open('newtext.txt', 'a') as file:
    for num in range(len(mylist)):
        file.write(mylist[num] + '\n')
        print('wrote: %s ' %(mylist[num]))
```

> newtext.txt
>
> > one
> >     two
> >     three

Comment: im now getting `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'`

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: @Thiplol i would unfortunately need the file youre opening to test the full code, are you able to post it?

Comment: added input file text to the original post

Comment: The problem is that it returns a list within a list. you would need to change your code to: `                print('wrote: %s ' %(result[1][num]))` if this answered your question, please mark my answer as answered :)

Comment: this did not fix the problem please check the current updated post

Comment: ah i used my mind a little and i got it working i guess :)

Comment: euhm its only returning 2 results of each  search:
`
['gaming', ['gaming laptop', 'gaming pc', 'gaming stoel', 'gaming chair', 'gaming headset', 'gaming', 'gaming monitor', 'gaming mouse', 'gaming muis', 'gaming pc kopen']]
wrote: gaming laptop 
wrote: gaming pc 
`
but there are clearly more